# Stormpath API blocks user on attempt of login once or verify repeatedly(on refresh)?

Tags: rest, backbone.js, jetty, dropwizard, stormpath

I am using stormpath's API to stores user details who are accessing the application(Backbone/require.js project).I integrated the REST API(running on Jetty Server) to stormapth's API to valid user credential.On validating user credential(once or repeatedly).It seems that stormpath does not respone for particular user within short span of time and server response connection refused or timeout.Is there any chance to stormpath block those user for few hours on validating repeatedly.

Answer (score 1):

I work at [Stormpath](https://stormpath.com)

At the moment we do not offer an account locking feature, though this is on our roadmap for the future.  In the meantime, we suggest storing a timestamp or history of login attempts in the account's custom data.  On each login attempt your application can look at this custom data and make a decision to block the user if they've tried too many times.

Hope this helps!